# Do I have to set the offset or cursor on everyline in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to learn PDFBox v2.0 but there seems to be few useful examples and tutorials to get started.

I want to create a simple PDF with text only (no images and fancy stuff) and it looks as the following:

```
1- Introduction
   This is an intro to the document

2- Data
   2.1- DataPart1
   This is some text here....
   2.2- DataPart2
   This is another text right here!

3- More Information
   Some important informational text here...
```

I have written the following code:

```
       PDPage firstPage = getNewPage();
PDPageContentStream firstContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, firstPage);
firstContentStream.setFont(HEADING_FONT, HEADING_FONT_SIZE);
firstContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLUE);
firstContentStream.beginText();
firstContentStream.newLineAtOffset(MARGIN, firstPage.getMediaBox().getHeight() - MARGIN);
firstContentStream.showText("1- Introduction");
firstContentStream.endText();

firstContentStream.setFont(TEXT_FONT, TEXT_FONT_SIZE);
firstContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
firstContentStream.beginText();
firstContentStream.showText("This document lists all the impacts that have been observed during the QA validation of the version v3.1 build");
firstContentStream.endText();
firstContentStream.close();
document.addPage(firstPage);
```

The text "This is the document intro" appears at the end of the page!

My question: do I have to set the cursor or the `offset` on every line???!

This seems like hard work. Does this mean I have to compute the string width and compare it to the page width and jump to new lines whenever the text fills the entire line?

I really don't understand.

And also how do I make it generate new pages whenever the current page is full?

Could you please give one simple example? Thanks in advance

Can't I just do something like:

```
contentStream.addTextOnNewLine("Some text here...");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635275/how-to-generate-multiple-lines-in-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541660/creating-a-new-pdf-document-using-pdfbox-api

Comment: no you can't just do something like `contentStream.addTextOnNewLine()` and expect magic to happen. Unlike itext, PDFBox is rather low level. I had the same problem a few years ago, it cost me an afternoon to implement wrapping and reset when new page, but this is of course individual to an application. (Moving to a new page is the same as the code you already have, i.e. `new PDPage`, then `new PDPageContentStream()`, and `PDDocument.addPage()`. You may also have a look at the Boxable project, they use PDFBox and operate on a higher level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all please be aware that PDFBox has a very low-level text drawing API only, i.e. most methods you call directly correspond to a single instruction in the PDF content stream. In particular PDFBox does not come with a (publicly accessible) layout'ing functionality but you essentially have to do the layout'ing in your code. This is both a freedom (you are not bound by the limits of an existing machinery) and a burden (you have to do everything yourself).

In your case that means:

> Does this mean I have to compute the string width and compare it to the page width and jump to new lines whenever the text fills the entire line?

Yes. Confer the answers @Tilman linked for you

- [How to generate multiple lines in PDF using Apache pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683618/1729265)
- [Creating a new PDF document using PDFBOX API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18781173/1729265)

and search some more on stackoverflow, there are further answer on different variations of that theme, e.g. for justified text blocks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20681996/1729265).

But there is a detail in your code which in your case makes things possibly harder than necessary:

> My question: do I have to set the cursor or the offset on every line???!

While you do have to re-position for every new line, it suffices to re-position by offset from the start of the previous line *if you still are in the same text object,* i.e. if you have not called `endText()` and `beginText()` in-between. E.g.:

```
PDPage firstPage = getNewPage();
PDPageContentStream firstContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, firstPage);
firstContentStream.setFont(HEADING_FONT, HEADING_FONT_SIZE);
firstContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLUE);
firstContentStream.beginText();
firstContentStream.newLineAtOffset(MARGIN, firstPage.getMediaBox().getHeight() - MARGIN);
firstContentStream.showText("1- Introduction");
// removed firstContentStream.endText();

firstContentStream.setFont(TEXT_FONT, TEXT_FONT_SIZE);
firstContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
// removed firstContentStream.beginText();
firstContentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -TEXT_FONT_SIZE); // reposition, tightly packed text lines
firstContentStream.showText("This document lists all the impacts that have been observed during the QA validation of the version v3.1 build");
firstContentStream.endText();
firstContentStream.close();
document.addPage(firstPage);
```

`newLineAtOffset(0, -TEXT_FONT_SIZE)` sets the text insertion position at the same x coordinate as the start of the previous line and `TEXT_FONT_SIZE` units lower.

(Using `TEXT_FONT_SIZE` here will result in pretty tightly set text lines; you may want to use a higher value, e.g. 1.4 times the font size.)

Considering your description you might want to use a positive x offset value for the line after a heading, though.

> The text "This is the document intro" appears at the end of the page!

This happens because the PDF instruction generated by `firstContentStream.beginText()` resets the text insertion position to the origin (0, 0) which by default is the lower left corner.

> And also how do I make it generate new pages whenever the current page is full?

Well, it does not happen automatically, you explicitly have to do that when you want to switch to a new page. And you do that more or less exactly like you created your first page.